# Code first migrations: How to view/manage in-db models/migrations?

Tags: entity-framework-migrations

Code first migrations stores the edmx model in compressed form in the database along with migrations. The Get-Migrations commandlet lists all migrations applied. What I don't understand is:

1. How to I display the migrations in human-readable form? The corresponding source code responsible for generating them might not always be at hand or even present (in the correct version).
2. How do I manage this migration trail? For example, an Update-Database with -force will still only work if the migration can be applied at all - but maybe I have already brought the database in a specific schema manually. How do I enforce migrations to just drop the knowledge of thinking there's a bogus migration still applied? A similar question for the other direction would apply.
3. Is there a way to dump the current edmx?

All questions apply to the commandlets or other external tools - I don't want to do any of this programmatically.